# Matlab - Can Handle Class Constructor use varargin to assign properties?

Tags: matlab, constructor, handle

I need some help for using varargin to assign properties in handle class.

Instead of using handle class, if I create a function with varargin, it works.

```
function out = testFunction(varargin)

% default values
startDate = '2011-11-01';
endDate = datestr(now,'yyyy-mm-dd');

% Map of parameter names to variable names
params_to_variables = containers.Map({'StartDate','EndDate'}, {'startDate','endDate'});

v = 1;
while v <= numel(varargin)
    param_name = varargin{v};
    if isKey(params_to_variables,param_name)
        assert(v+1<=numel(varargin));
        v = v+1;
        % Trick: use feval on anonymous function to use assignin to this workspace
        feval(@()assignin('caller',params_to_variables(param_name),varargin{v}));
    else
        error('Unsupported parameter: %s',varargin{v});
    end
    v=v+1;
end
end
```

But my current task is to create a super-class with many properties. There are various types of sub-classes. Different sub-class may need to use different properties. So when I create an instance of a super-class or sub-class, I need the input to be very flexible. As the example above, one sub-class only need the property 'startDate', and the other sub-class only need the property 'endDate'. Here is my code.

```
classdef superclass < handle
    properties 
        startDate
        endDate
    end

    methods
        function obj = superclass(varargin)
            % Map of parameter names to variable names
            params_to_variables = containers.Map({'StartDate','EndDate'}, {'startDate','endDate'});

            v = 1;
            while v <= numel(varargin)
                 param_name = varargin{v};
                 if isKey(params_to_variables,param_name)
                    assert(v+1<=numel(varargin));
                    v = v+1;
                             feval(@()assignin('caller',params_to_variables(param_name),varargin{v}));
                 else
                    error('Unsupported parameter: %s',varargin{v});
                 end
                 v=v+1;
             end
        end
    end
end
```

Basically I just copy and paste, it doesn't work. 
So I change

```
  feval(@()assignin('caller',params_to_variables(param_name),varargin{v}));
```

to

```
feval(@()assignin('caller',strcat('obj.',params_to_variables(param_name),varargin{v}));
```

or

```
feval(@()assignin('base',strcat('obj.',params_to_variables(param_name),varargin{v}));
```

or

```
evalin('caller',...
strcat('obj.',params_to_variables(param_name),'=',num2str(varargin{v})));
```

or

```
evalin('base',...
strcat('obj.',params_to_variables(param_name),'=',num2str(varargin{v})));
```

None of them works. If anyone can tell me how to solve this problem or provide me an alternative way, I appreciate it. Thank you.